# Why does attribute casing change in the DOM vs source code?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I've found that when you try to get the original casing of an attribute name it always returns the name in all lowercase.  Why does this happen and how can we get around this?

Please look at this easy example below.  The source code shows that the second attribute of the input field is "SomeAttribute" when I grab the value of that attribute it is changed to "someattribute".

```html
<input type="text" SomeAttribute="test" />

<script>
  
var attributeName = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].attributes[1].name;
alert(attributeName);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML attributes are case insensitive, so both will process the same by the browsers.

However, as written in [W3C attribute page](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp), "W3C recommends lowercase in HTML4, and demands lowercase for stricter document types like XHTML.".

To avoid further problems, use only lower case as the attributes name.

Comment: Has this always been the case? I'm surprised I haven't noticed this over the past decade or so.

Comment: I believe it's every browser and its quirks:
http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/attributes-casing/